# Custom words in Package 'qdap' in R

Tags: r, text-mining, qdap

I am using the qdap package in R to do a spell check. I run the below code and gives an output like this

```
which_misspelled("I use a 50Gb broadband connection") 

> 4           5 
>"gb" "broadband"
```

The words make sense but the corrections for these are irrelevant.Is there any option where we could give our custom words list for this function to not filter on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `which_misspelled()` contains the argument `dictionary =` which defaults to [qdapDictionaries::GradyAugmented](https://rdrr.io/cran/qdapDictionaries/man/GradyAugmented.html). If your input of words isn't present in there, it will be considered *misspelled*.

If you want for example the word `"gb"` to be recognized as correct spelling, you should define a new `dictionary` :

```
library(qdap)
dict <- c(qdapDictionaries::GradyAugmented, "gb")
which_misspelled("I use a 50Gb broadband connection", dictionary = dict)
#          5 
#"broadband"
```